# ZPL code for barcode withd

Tags: c#, zpl

How can I control the width of the barcode? I use the ^BY3 command but its too small when I try ^BY4 the width is too narrow. Is there any way to control the width without adding another character?

Answer (score 1):

What I usually end up doing in such scenarios is to use some kind of label design software (for example: [Zebra Designer](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/zebralink/zebra-designer.html)), Design the barcode as needed and use the print to file option to inspect how the barcode was generated. That way you can make your changes and compare the output.